# Exception Inserting Image To MSAccess Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

[image]Here I am inserting an image in msaccess database (accdb). I am not able to figure out why this is generating expcetion. It says Error in insert into statement.

```
String q = @"Insert Into tblModal (ModalName, CategoryId, Gender, Type, Description, image, LastUpdated) values ('" +
                txtModalName.Text + "','" + categoryId + "','" + gender + "','"+txtType.Text +"', '" + txtDescription.Text + "',@pic, '" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "')";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(q);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pic", Check.imageToByteArray(pictureBoxPhoto.Image));
            int res;
            res = br.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

Comment: kindly put the actual error message.

Comment: Use query parameters for every parameters in your query and your problem will gone.

Comment: thanks @mybirthname.. you saved my day

Comment: If your image field is an attachment type, you cannot insert an image into MS Access using SQL DML statements. Images are complex data types that are actually multiple value fields comprising of metadata points. You will need to launch a [DAO instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835669.aspx)  and run `LoadFromFile`.